# SingleOrDefault: Catch just "Sequence contains more than one element" InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, invalidoperationexception

In our project we recently added an import tool for old data, in which we convert this old data to usable objects in our application. In this import we have the following piece of code:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    try
    {
        var cluster = session.Query<ClusterState>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == clusterString);
        return cluster != null
            ? (ClusterId) cluster.AggregateId
            : null;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        if (String.Equals(e.Message, "Sequence contains more than one element"))
        {
            Logger.Warn("More than one cluster found with the given string: {0}", clusterString);
            if (...)
            {
                return ...
            }
            return null;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

My issue is the following line:

```
if (String.Equals(e.Message, "Sequence contains more than one element"))
```

It works local, but not on the server. The reason for this is we have a Dutch server, so instead of `"Sequence contains more than one element"` it gives a `"Reeks bevat meerdere elementen"` `InvalidOperationException`. Now I know I can modify the code to this:

```
if (String.Equals(e.Message, "Sequence contains more than one element")
    || String.Equals(e.Message, "Reeks bevat meerdere elementen"))
```

Of course this works, and I don't think we intend to have a different language server in the future, but still, it's pretty bad code and if the message ever changes with a new .NET / LINQ version, this doesn't work anymore.

So, is there any other way to catch just `"Sequence contains more than one element" InvalidOperationException`, and not any other `InvalidOperationExceptions`?

Should I add a `Count` check or something to see if I receive more than one matching element instead of the Try-Catch, or is there a distinguished way to filter just the `"Sequence contains more than one element"` Exceptions? Or should I just catch all "InvalidOperationExceptions" and add an additional log-line so we get notifications of these exceptions?

Comment: This exception would not normally be considered a recoverable runtime exception. That's (probably) why they did not create a separate exception class for it. You should not handle this error with exceptions, get a List and look at Count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set culture of the program to en-US can resolve your problem

Example :

```
 // Change current culture
  CultureInfo culture;
  if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-FR")
     culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
  else
     culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");

  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

---

Create your extension method and raise your own exception as alternate solution

```
public static TSource SingleOnlyOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
        if (predicate == null) { throw new   
                         ArgumentNullException("predicate");    
    }

    IEnumerable<TSource> matchingItems = source.Where(predicate);
    int matchedItemCount = matchingItems.Count;

        switch (matchedItemCount)
        {
            case 0: return default(TSource);
            case 1: return matchingItems[0]; // Or Single() 
            default: throw new Exception("Too many element exist for    condition");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that does indeed sound promising. The Dutch exceptions are kinda annoying and badly translated to begin with and we often use Google to translate the Exceptions to know which English error is given. If we can make the entire application English, despite having a Dutch server, it would benefit for more than this problem. (I'll see if I can get this to work and if I can I'll accept your answer. If I can't, I might ask for more details on how to do this.)

Comment: I discussed this with my colleagues and also asked if there is a reason we don't always use an English Culture. There most certainly is, because the Dutch format has different Date and Time, different Decimals, etc. It currently uses the default Culture of the machine. Even though my language is in English on my machine, everything else like dates and times are in set to Dutch. (This wasn't clear in my question, so your solution is still a good answer, but unfortunately doesn't work for us.) I think I'm removing the try-catch and just do a `Select` and then see `if` it contains more than one.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - you can try to create extension method may this helps you ..check udpated answer